# Output in variable shouldn't be interpreted as command

Tags: shell-script, variable, assignment

So this question was asked some times already, but the answers didn't seem to work for me. So I have this simple script

```
#!/bin/bash
charon_id = $(pidof charon)
kill -1 $charon_id
```

And console says `charon_id: command  not found`*

I've tried different versions, with `"` around the `$( )`, `;` after the lines, even the `$(... 2>&1)` I saw somewhere. Nothing has helped so far. Suggestions?

* translated from console language into English

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is with spaces

You wrote

```
charon_id = $(pidof charon)
```

This means "run the command `charon_id` with two parameters; first is the `=` character and the second is the output of the `$(..)` command

It should be

```
charon_id=$(pidof charon)
```

Now you assign the output to the variable.

Comment: Now I feel like the noob I am in shell scripting D: Thanks alot! ;)

Comment: @GreenThor don't worry about feeling like a noob; you should have seen the mistakes I made when I was one.  Fortunately that was almost 30 years ago; I've learned since then :-)